# How to handle time Interval in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm stuck following time interval logic. If any time interval between end time and start time, we have to isolate that data.

I used to query like this,

```
DECLARE @EMP_DETAILS TABLE
                     (ID INT,
                      EMP_ID INT, 
                      START_TIME VARCHAR(10),
                      END_TIME VARCHAR(10)
                     )

INSERT INTO @EMP_DETAILS
    SELECT 1, 50, '09:30', '10:30'
    UNION
    SELECT 2, 50, '10:30', '11:45'
    UNION
    SELECT 3, 50, '11:45', '12:15'
    UNION
    SELECT 4, 50, '12:15', '13:40'
    UNION
    SELECT 5, 50, '14:00', '14:40'
    UNION
    SELECT 6, 50, '14:40', '15:10'
    UNION
    SELECT 7, 50, '15:10', '18:00'


SELECT 
    A.EMP_ID, A.START_TIME, A.END_TIME,
    B.START_TIME, B.END_TIME 
FROM 
    @EMP_DETAILS A 
LEFT JOIN 
    @EMP_DETAILS B ON A.END_TIME = B.START_TIME
                   AND A.EMP_ID = B.EMP_ID
```

My expected output should look like this:

```
EMP_ID  START_TIME  END_TIME  RN
---------------------------------
50      09:30       10:30     1
50      10:30       11:45     1
50      11:45       12:15     1
50      14:00       14:40     2
50      14:40       15:10     2
```

I have hope, you're clear about what I am trying to say..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What **version** of SQL Server are you using? As of SQL Server **2008**, there's a *proper* `TIME` datatype - you should always use those most appropriate datatypes, instead of just squeezing everything into a string ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple:

```
select sq.EMP_ID, sq.START_TIME, sq.END_TIME, sq.RN
from (
  select e.*,
    sum(case when xt.ID is not null then 0 else 1 end)
    over(partition by e.emp_id order by e.start_time) + 1 as [RN],
    xt.ID as [SameRange]
  from @EMP_DETAILS e
    left join @EMP_DETAILS xt on xt.EMP_ID = e.EMP_ID and xt.START_TIME = e.END_TIME
      and xt.ID != e.ID
) sq
where sq.SameRange is not null;
```

Excluding unwanted rows is easy and can be done with a simple `left join`. Numbering them, however, is a bit more tricky. You will need SQL Server 2012 or later version for the running total - `sum(...) over(order by ...)` - to work.

The only possible issue here can arise if your table contains duplicated or zero intervals (that is, `start_time = end_time` within the same row). Most probably, you would need to replace the table with a subquery which will provide distinct values.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there is a way to compute the `RN` column in a single query, but I can't think of it right now.  So, with the use of cursor, the following creates just what you want:

```
DECLARE @EMP_DETAILS TABLE (
  ID INT,
  EMP_ID INT, 
  START_TIME VARCHAR(10),
  END_TIME VARCHAR(10)
)
DECLARE @OUTPUT TABLE (
  ID INT,
  EMP_ID INT,
  START_TIME VARCHAR(10),
  END_TIME VARCHAR(10),
  RN INT NULL
)

INSERT INTO @EMP_DETAILS VALUES
(1, 50, '09:30', '10:30'),
(2, 50, '10:30', '11:45'),
(3, 50, '11:45', '12:15'),
(4, 50, '12:15', '13:40'),
(5, 50, '14:00', '14:40'),
(6, 50, '14:40', '15:10'),
(7, 50, '15:10', '18:00')

INSERT INTO @OUTPUT
SELECT A.ID, A.EMP_ID, A.START_TIME, A.END_TIME, NULL
FROM   @EMP_DETAILS A 
       INNER JOIN @EMP_DETAILS B ON A.EMP_ID = B.EMP_ID AND A.END_TIME = B.START_TIME

DECLARE @ID INT, @I INT, @J INT = 1

SELECT @I = MIN(ID) - 1
FROM   @OUTPUT

DECLARE CR CURSOR LOCAL FOR
  SELECT ID
  FROM   @OUTPUT
  ORDER BY ID

OPEN CR
FETCH NEXT FROM CR INTO @ID

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
  IF @ID > @I + 1
    SET @J = @J + 1

  UPDATE @OUTPUT
  SET    RN = @J
  WHERE  ID = @ID

  SET @I = @ID

  FETCH NEXT FROM CR INTO @ID
END

CLOSE CR
DEALLOCATE CR

SELECT EMP_ID, START_TIME, END_TIME, RN
FROM   @OUTPUT
ORDER BY ID
```

Instead of doing a `LEFT JOIN`, I used an `INNER JOIN`, which eliminated the unwanted rows.  Then, the `RN` column was computed by moving through the records in the `@OUTPUT` table with a `CURSOR` to find a break in the `ID` sequence.  If there was a break, then we increment `RN`.  This assumes `ID` will never have missing numbers in the actual data.

This is the output from the above query:

```
EMP_ID      START_TIME END_TIME   RN
----------- ---------- ---------- -----------
50          09:30      10:30      1
50          10:30      11:45      1
50          11:45      12:15      1
50          14:00      14:40      2
50          14:40      15:10      2
```